# Do I need a dedicated request object and a response object in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

An example is to create an student object.

If I create one, the user doesn't have to enter a student id as it is generated at the back end.

If I return a student with an id, it returns more than the properties of the original student object used to create. Probably it contains what subject the student has enrolled it.

Should I create a dedicated request and response object based on the need or purpose?

Comment: I would suggest declaring just one object "student" for both request and response and mark the `id` property as optional, then leveraging vendor extension to document which property is required in certain scenarios (requests, responses, etc)

Comment: @wing328 Do you mean that there would be another document to indicate the different scenarios? Or can it be placed in the swagger io?

Comment: I mean document it in the same swagger spec and use vendor extensions to describe the additional information. Pls refer to https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#specification-extensions and https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Vendor-Extensions for more info.